Max number of sides of a 3-dimensional cross-section of an N-dimensional cube
I have been thinking about this for a while but have been unable to come up with an answer; if you take an N-dimensional cube, what is the maximum number of faces that a 3-dimensional cross-section of that cube can have? Or to generalize, what is the maximum number of faces on a k-dimensional cross-section of an N-dimensional cube?

It seems like it might be pretty easy to come up with a good lower bound, but harder to prove the actual upper bound. I suppose you have already figured out the answer for $N=3, k=2$?

For N=3, k=2 the maximum faces would be 6, and I'm not certain but it seems that for k=N-1, the maximum is 2N

Maybe each face is the intersection of one of the $2N$ faces with the same $k$-dimensional space.  On the other hand, for $k=1$ the answer is always $2$.

Note, that the $n$D hypercube ($o3o...o3o4x$, $n$ nodes) in its vertex-first direction has $n+1$ vertex layers. Its according orthogonal section always has $o3o...o3o$ ($n-1$ nodes) symmetry, and indeed is given by this very symbol (then representing just points) at the $0^{th}$ and $n+1^{st}$ layer, while all others are each some $(k-1)$-rectified simplex - represented by $o3o...o3q3o...o3o$, still $n$ nodes, the $k^{th}$ of which being marked - when representing the $k^{th}$ layer section, where $q$ represents an edge size, which is $\sqrt2$ as large as the hypercube's edge size $x$.
Further, according sections between 2 consecutive vertex-layer sections $o3o...o3q3o3o...o3o$ and $o3o...o3o3q3o...o3o$ (still $n-1$ nodes, then being the $(k-1)$-rectified and $k$-rectified $(n-1)$D simplex respectively) then are given by the Coxeter-Dynkin diagram $o3o...o3y3z3o...o3o$ and describe $(k-1)$-truncated simplex variants. Here edge size $y$ decreases from $q$ to zero, while $z$ increases from zero to $q$.
Next we observe that for every $j$ the total $j$-face count of a $k$-truncated simplex at least is equal, but often is larger than that of either of the $k$-rectified and $(k+1)$-rectified simplex. On the other hand total $j$-face counts don't change when considering those $y$,$z$ variants, thence we are allowed to consider for simplicity the uniform $x$,$x$ variants instead.
Finally it is obvious that the "largest" $k$-truncated simplex as a cross-section of an $n$D hypercube occurs for $n$ odd at $k=(n-1)/2$ (orthogonal midsection). For $n$ even it occurs both at $k=(n-2)/2$ and $k=n/2$, because the midsection here would represent a vertex layer instead.

Thus for the cube $o3o4x$ we get $x3x$, the hexagon, having 6 vertices and 6 sides.
For the tesseract $o3o3o4x$ we get $x3x3o$ or $o3x3x$, the truncated tetrahedron (in mutually inverted orientations), having 12 vertices, 18 edges, and 8 faces.
For the penteract $o3o3o3o4x$ we get the $o3x3x3o$, the decachoron, having 30 vertices, 60 edges, 40 faces, and 10 cells.
For the hexeract $o3o3o3o3o4x$ we get $o3x3x3o3o$ or $o3o3x3x3o$, the bitruncated hexateron (in mutually inverted orientations), having a face vector of 60, 150, 140, 60, 12.
For the hepteract $o3o3o3o3o3o4x$ we get $o3o3x3x3o3o$, the tetradecapeton, with face vector 140, 420, 490, 280, 84, 14.
For the octeract $o3o3o3o3o3o3o4x$ we get $o3o3x3x3o3o3o$ or $o3o3o3x3x3o3o$, the tritruncated octaexon (in mutually inverted orientations), with face vector 280, 980, 1400, 1050, 448, 112, 16.

--- rk
